# Measuring download/upload data over network

Tags: java, c++, windows, networking

I want to develop an application on Windows platform in which I need to know how much data a user has uploaded and downloaded in megabytes. Based upon this I have to perform some action, but I wasn't able to start.

My problem can be solved if this can be measured in any language (e.g., C++ or Java).

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you do this in Java, you may want to have a look at the [DiskFileItem](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.html) class, which is an implementation of the FileItem interface. This interface represents a file or form item that was received within a multipart/form-data POST request, it has getSize() method, which returns the size of the file item.